# How to package kivy and python to executable file in Ubuntu?

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, kivy, pyinstaller

I have a Kivy application consisting of many Python and KV files. I want to create an executable so that it can be run in Ubuntu by an end user.

https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/packaging.html documentation mentions how to package in OS X and Windows, but there is no mention about Linux distributions.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a scheme that I have used. This script creates a `.sh` file to run the python/kivy app:

```
#!/usr/bin/tcsh

set APP_NAME="HandAndFoot"

# setup output
set OUTPUT="${APP_NAME}.sh"
if $#argv > 0 then
    set OUTPUT=$argv[1]
endif
echo "output will be to $OUTPUT"

# copy initial part of shell script into output file
cp ${APP_NAME}.basis $OUTPUT

# create a tar file of the Hand And Foot app
rm -f tmp.tar
tar cf app.tar *.py *.kv dropbox-trusted-certs.crt dialogs/*.py dialogs/*.kv dialogs/*.png resources/*.png resources/*.ico resources/default/*.png

# add the uuencoded version of the app to the end of the output file
uuencode app.tar app.tar >> $OUTPUT
chmod 755 $OUTPUT

# How does a file named "0" get created?? Don't know, but this gets rid of it
rm -f 0
```

The above script creates a `HandAndFoot.sh` that contains a `tar` of the app. In this case the app is called `HandAndFoot`. When the `HandAndFoot.sh` is run, it executes the `main.py` script of the app.

In addition to the above script, another file (in this case named `HandAndFoot.basis`) is required:

```
#!/bin/bash

APP_NAME="HandAndFoot"
PYTHON="NONE"
# check if python3 is installed
pyvers=$(python3 -V 2>&1)
echo $pyvers
regex="Python 3.*"
if [[ $pyvers =~ $regex ]]
then
    PYTHON="python3"
else
    # check if python is installed
    pyvers=$(python -V 2>&1)
    if [[ $pyvers =~ $regex ]]
    then
        PYTHON="python"
    fi
fi
if [[ $PYTHON != "NONE" ]]
then
    kivyimport=$(
    $PYTHON 2>&1  <<EOF
import kivy
EOF
    )
    kivyregex=".*Kivy .*"
    if ! [[ $kivyimport =~ $kivyregex ]]
    then
        echo "Python is installed, but Kivy is also required"
        echo "Use you package Manager or 'apt-get' to install Kivy"
        exit
    fi
else
    echo "Python and Kivy are not installed, but are required for the $APP_NAME app"
    echo "Use your Package Manager or 'apt-get' to install Python and Kivy"
    exit
fi

match=$(grep --text --line-number '^PAYLOAD:$' $0 | cut -d ':' -f 1)
payload_start=$((match + 1))
tail -n +$payload_start $0 | uudecode
rm -rf /tmp/$APP_NAME
mkdir /tmp/$APP_NAME
mv app.tar /tmp/$APP_NAME
cd /tmp/$APP_NAME
tar xvf app.tar
$PYTHON main.py &
exit



PAYLOAD:
```

The final script checks for Python and Kivy installation and runs `main.py` if python and kivy are installed. These scripts can be modified for different apps as needed.